# Change language to Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, locale, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the *datetimepicker* of Bootstrap, it's working pretty well. The thing is that it's in english, and I need it in spanish, I had read some post but nothing works to me. my HTML is defined as:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class='input-group date datepicker' data-date-startdate="{{$student->middle}}" name="datepicker" >
    <input type='text' class="form-control placementT" id="fecha">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the javascript, I have only one function related with the datetimepicker, this is:

```
$('.input-group.date').each(function() {
  $(this).datetimepicker().on('dp.hide',function (ev) {
    //something
  });
});
```

So, what should I add to change this to spanish?I had read that this is with *locale.js* but can I add the definition of days and months inside my javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add locale, reference can be found [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#locale)

For spanish `locale: 'es'`

Script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/es.js"></script>
```

DateTimePicker in Spanish

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.input-group.date').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'es',
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/es.js"></script>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
     <div class='input-group date datepicker' name="datepicker" >
          <input type='text' class="form-control placementT" id="fecha">
             <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                   </span>
            </span>
      </div>
</div>
```