# Add many CDN bundles in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Datetime picker for birthdays, as you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271030/change-language-to-bootstrap-datetimepicker), the solution requires the use of many links and script sources.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/es.js"></script>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class='input-group date datepicker' name="datepicker" >
      <input type='text' class="form-control placementT" id="fecha">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
               </span>
        </span>
  </div>
```

I want to use mvc bundles, with links to those scripts and stylesheets. But the solution I found: [How to setup bundles using CDN in ASP.NET MVC?](http://www.siddharthpandey.net/setup-bundles-using-cdn-in-asp-net-mvc/)
does not explain how to include many links in a bundle. Instead, uses one link per bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")
   .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css")
            .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

As you can see, I would have to 6 different bundles.Add. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
bundles.Add(....,"https://maxcdn","https link","another link")
```

How can I do it ? I want to include that bundle in my view like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myCustomBundle")
```

Comment: every links that you want to add in the bundle are different? or for example you want add 3 links just for bootstrap?

Comment: yes they are different, I need different js files.

Comment: Duplicate Question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248612/create-a-script-bundle-from-multiple-cdn-locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an example you can change parameters according to your need.

**Example**

The `cdnHost` parameter refers to alternate URL for the bundle when it is stored in a content delivery network. The cdn bundle is supposed to be loaded as one file and should contain a combined content of all files uploaded on cdn for example server path is `https://ajax.googleapis.com/` in your case
then you can load multiple script file as one bundle you just need to provide relative path of other files in include method.

```
var cdnHost = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/";
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularCDN", cdnHost).Include(
                            "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js",
                            "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-cookies.js",
                            "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-route.js"));
```

i hope it'll work for you.